# PlayFramework 2 template testing

Tags: java, junit, playframework, playframework-2.0

In the latest [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaFunctionalTest), this template test is given as an example.

```
@Test
public void renderTemplate() {
  Content html = views.html.index.render("Coco");
  assertThat(contentType(html)).isEqualTo("text/html");
  assertThat(contentAsString(html)).contains("Coco");
}
```

But how am I supposed to run this? I tried it on its own, inside the run() method on a fake server, a real server, along side an actual running server, and I always get this error.

```
[error] Test ApplicationTest.testInServer failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.
```

There are literally two pages on testing in the documentation and I have no idea how to actually run any of these tests. Is there an example class anywhere that doesn't use deprecated methods (things have changed since Play 1 and most things don't work any more).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why not use selenium ?

See the last part of the help : http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaFunctionalTest

Comment: This is what I'm doing now, I've given up with JUnit/Spec.

Answer (score 3):

You need to setup the Http Context first.

Example with Mockito:

```
@Test
public void indexTest() {
    //setup HTTP Context
    Http.Context context = Mockito.mock(Http.Context.class);
    //mocking flash session, request, etc... as required 
    Http.Flash flash = Mockito.mock(Http.Flash.class);
    when(context.flash()).thenReturn(flash);
    Http.Context.current.set(context);

    //run your test
    Content html = views.html.index.render("Coco");
    assertThat(contentType(html)).isEqualTo("text/html");
    assertThat(contentAsString(html)).contains("Coco");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run "play test" from your command-line.  That will runs all the tests in the test folder.

Comment: That is how I ran the test, there was an error which I copied into my post.